# Concatenating selected columns and outputting into new column

Tags: excel, vba

My issue is that the concatenating process stops as soon as there are 2 cells in the columns that need concatenating. Once reaching that point, the macro stops concatenating the remainder of the cells in column range selected, and the output column remains empty.

I’m working in Excel and need the macro to concatenate the cells in the selected column range, and output the result into a new column.

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks

```vb
Option Explicit
Sub ConcatenateSelectedColumns()
    Dim ColIndex As Long
    Dim rngRow As Range
    Dim Cell As Range
    Dim ConcatenatedValue As String
    ' Check if a range is selected
    If Not TypeName(Selection) = "Range" Then
        MsgBox "Please select the columns you want to concatenate.", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    ' Add a new column to the right of the selected columns
    With Selection
        ColIndex = .Cells(1).Offset(0, .Columns.Count).Column
        Columns(ColIndex).Insert
        Cells(1, ColIndex).Value = "NewColumn"
        ' Loop through selected cells
        For Each rngRow In .Rows
            ' Stop at the blank row if whole column(s) are selected
            If Application.CountA(rngRow) = 0 Then Exit For
            ConcatenatedValue = ""
            For Each Cell In rngRow.Cells
                ' Concatenate values from selected columns
                ConcatenatedValue = ConcatenatedValue & Cell.Value
            Next Cell
            Cells(rngRow.Row, ColIndex) = ConcatenatedValue
        Next rngRow
    End With
End Sub
```

I was trying to create a macro that concatenated the cells in the selected column range, and outputs the concatenated values into a new column. This code does some of the job, however, when I run into a row that is completely empty in the selected column range then the macro stops outputting the concatenated values.

Comment: Yeah, that's what the code says, `If Application.CountA(rngRow) = 0 Then Exit For` If the row is empty, then stop.

Comment: Remove or commen `If Application.CountA(rngRow) = 0 Then Exit For`. There is a comment `' Stop at the blank row`.

Answer (score 1):

A few small edits:

- Moved `Cells(1, ColIndex).Value = "NewColumn"` so the for-loop doesn't change the header to something weird and put it in an If-clause so that itself doesn't change concatenated values if it wasn't a column-select
- Added a `lRow` variable to check if it's the actual end of values to be processed, which I use in the If-clause with the Exit For

Code:

```
Sub ConcatenateSelectedColumns()
    Dim ColIndex As Long
    Dim rngRow As Range
    Dim Cell As Range
    Dim ConcatenatedValue As String
    ' Check if a range is selected
    If Not TypeName(Selection) = "Range" Then
        MsgBox "Please select the columns you want to concatenate.", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Dim lRow As Long
    ' Add a new column to the right of the selected columns
    With Selection
        ColIndex = .Cells(1).Offset(0, .Columns.Count).Column
        lRow = Cells(Rows.Count, ColIndex).End(xlUp).Row
        Columns(ColIndex).Insert
        ' Loop through selected cells
        For Each rngRow In .Rows
            ' Stop at the blank row if whole column(s) are selected
            If Application.CountA(rngRow) = 0 And rngRow.Row > lRow Then Exit For
            ConcatenatedValue = ""
            For Each Cell In rngRow.Cells
                ' Concatenate values from selected columns
                ConcatenatedValue = ConcatenatedValue & Cell.Value
            Next Cell
            Cells(rngRow.Row, ColIndex) = ConcatenatedValue
        Next rngRow
        If Selection.Rows.Count = Rows.Count Then Cells(1, ColIndex).Value = "NewColumn"
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

### Concatenate Selected Rows

- This will give you a bit more freedom in what you can concatenate. The rule is simple: keep each row in a single area. The error handler will alert you if you 'overdo' it.
- Note in the screenshot, how the formatting was copied while inserting the column. This is the behavior that Excel chose (`xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove`). You could choose the opposite, or use `.Clear` right above `.Value` to get rid of any.

[image]

```vb
Sub ConcatenateSelectedRows()
    Const PROC_TITLE As String = "Concatenate Selected Rows"
    ' Start an error-handling routine.
    On Error GoTo ClearError
    
    ' Define constants.
    Const CONCAT_COLUMN_TITLE As String = "NewColumn"
    Const AUTOFIT_COLUMN As Boolean = True
    
    ' Invalidate the selection.
    If Selection Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Nothing selected.", vbCritical, PROC_TITLE
        Exit Sub
    End If
    If Not TypeOf Selection Is Range Then
        MsgBox "No range selected.", vbCritical, PROC_TITLE
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Define a jagged array to hold the initial row index (1),
    ' the number of rows (2), the number of columns (3) and a 2D one-based array
    ' (4 ('Data')) holding the values of each area of the selection.
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = Selection
    Dim aCount As Long: aCount = srg.Areas.Count
    Dim Jag() As Variant: ReDim Jag(1 To aCount, 1 To 5)
    Dim Data() As Variant: ReDim Data(1 To 1, 1 To 1)
    
    ' Declare additional variables.
    Dim arg As Range, a As Long, arCount As Long, acCount As Long, alCol As Long
    Dim dCol As Long
    
    For Each arg In srg.Areas
        arCount = arg.Rows.Count
        acCount = arg.Columns.Count
        a = a + 1
        ' an integer by 1 smaller than the first worksheet row of the area:
        Jag(a, 1) = arg.Row - 1
        Jag(a, 2) = arCount
        Jag(a, 3) = acCount
        If arCount * acCount = 1 Then
            Data(1, 1) = arg.Value
            Jag(a, 4) = Data
        Else
            Jag(a, 4) = arg.Value
        End If
        alCol = arg.Column + acCount
        If alCol > dCol Then dCol = alCol
    Next arg
    
    ' Define the destination array ('Data').
    Dim dri As Long: dri = Jag(1, 1)
    Dim drCount As Long: drCount = Jag(aCount, 1) + Jag(aCount, 2)
    ReDim Data(1 To drCount, 1 To 1)
    
    ' Write the header only if the first row was not selected.
    If dri > 0 Then Data(1, 1) = CONCAT_COLUMN_TITLE
    
    ' Declare additional variables.
    Dim ar As Long, ac As Long, dr As Long, rVal As Variant, rStr As String
    
    ' Write the values from the jagged array to the destination array.
    For a = 1 To aCount
        dri = Jag(a, 1)
        For ar = 1 To Jag(a, 2)
            dr = ar + dri
            acCount = Jag(a, 3)
            For ac = 1 To acCount
                rVal = Jag(a, 4)(ar, ac)
                If Not IsError(rVal) Then
                    rStr = rStr & rVal
                End If
            Next ac
            Data(dr, 1) = rStr
            rStr = vbNullString
        Next ar
    Next a
                
    ' Write the values from the array to a newly inserted column.
    With srg.Worksheet.Columns(dCol)
        .Insert ', xlFormatFromRightOrBelow ' xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
        With .Offset(, -1).Resize(drCount)
            Debug.Print srg.Address(0, 0) & vbLf & .Address(0, 0)
            .Value = Data
            If AUTOFIT_COLUMN Then .EntireColumn.AutoFit
        End With
    End With
    
    ' Inform.
    MsgBox "Selected rows concatenated.", vbInformation, PROC_TITLE

ProcExit:
    Exit Sub
ClearError:
    ' Continue error-handling routine.
    MsgBox "Run-time error '" & Err.Number & vbLf & vbLf _
        & Err.Description, vbCritical, PROC_TITLE
    Resume ProcExit
End Sub
```